# WindowManager.LayoutParams - How to place a button in bottom right corner

Tags: android, android-layout, overlay

I want to add an overlay button in a corner using this code:

```
int width = 100; //button width
int height = 50; 
int x = 400;
int y = 50;
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(width, height, x, y,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, 
            PixelFormat.OPAQUE);
```

But it adds the button in the upper left corner and makes the layout fill the whole screen.

Am I passing invalid values making everything reset to defaults?

How can I place that button in a corner?

Comment: In android, a Point(0, 0) corresponds to the upper left corner. Did you take this into account ?

Comment: This would be a lot easier to create with a FrameLayout.

Answer (score 2):

... years later, hit a similar question.  The solution was the gravity on the LayoutParams:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = ...;
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout for layoutParams

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(width, height);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);`
button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

after that add button in parent **Relative Layout**.

Comment: Is it posible without a RelativeLayout?